# String Manipulation using Split Method

Tags: c#, string, split

I having a problem on using `Split Method()`.

I have a string like this:

```
string diagnosis = "001.00 00 002.01 00 003.00 01";
```

And output should be:

```
001.00
002.01
003.00
```

I tried in this two ways to remove the two digits:

## 1

```
    string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = diagnosis.Split();
    if (DiagnosisCodesParts[x].Length > 3)
       {
         //here
       }
```

And..

## 2

```
string DiagnosisCodestemp = diagnosis.Replace(" 00 ", " ").Replace(" 01 ", " ").Replace(" 02 ", " ")
```

**Is there other way to remove the two digits?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearest to me would be

```
Regex.Matches(diagnosis, @"\d+\.\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Regular Expressions. Example:

```
var data = "001.00 00 002.01 00 003.00 01";

var re = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\d+)\ \d+\ ?");
var matches = re.Matches(data);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++ )
{
    var m = matches[i];
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This outputs:

```
001.00
002.01
003.00
```

Comment: the is output is 001.00 00
002.01 01
003.00 00

Comment: @SilverFang I got that output when running it on my computer. I think something else is wrong. Try copy-pasting my code. I promise it works.

Answer (score 1):

If we can rely that valid item length is 6 that:

```
var items = diagnosis.Split(' ')
                     .Where(item => item.Length == 6)
                     .ToList();
```

If condition is item Length GREATER THAN 2:

```
var items = diagnosis.Split(' ')
                     .Where(item => item.Length > 2)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the parts with more than three consecutive characters like this:

```
var resultSet = from sz in diagnosis.Split(new char[] {' '})
                  where sz.Length > 3
                  select sz;
```

or to get any string with a decimal point in it:

```
var resultSet = from sz in diagnosis.Split(new char[] {' '})
                  where sz.Contains(".")
                  select sz;
```

then you can output it like this:

```
foreach(var entry in resultSet)
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result so that it only contains strings that are longer than two characters:

```
string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = diagnosis.Split().Where(s => s.Length > 2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work -

```
var arr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("001.00 00 002.01 00 003.00 01",@"\s\d{2}\s*").Take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this and eliminate empty strings

```
var DiagnosisCodesParts = Regex.Split(diagnosis, "\\s\\d\\d\\s?");
```

or use this and trim results.

```
var DiagnosisCodesParts = Regex.Split(diagnosis, "\\d\\d");
```